# Get jwt token using http post method and then pass it in each api method on swagger page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I want to do the following authentication in swagger page:

1. Pass the username and password to a swagger authentication window.
2. Add the username and password to a post request body to an authentication endpoint (like http:localhost:1111/login).
3. Get the response with a jwt token.
4. Add the jwt token into the body of all http methods in swagger page (like: "Authorization: Bearer <jwt_token>")

I didn't find anything about creating your own SecuritySchema or SecurityContext, so maybe it is possible to do with library classes and methods.

I can add jwt token into the body of all http methods as mentioned here: [Spring Boot & Swagger UI. Set JWT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545286/spring-boot-swagger-ui-set-jwt-token)
And add a window with username and password and send post method to specific endpoint as mentioned here: [How to configure oAuth2 with password flow with Swagger ui in spring boot rest application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054384/how-to-configure-oauth2-with-password-flow-with-swagger-ui-in-spring-boot-rest-a).
But I don't know how to make the authentication I mentioned earlier.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I use: sprint boot 2.2.5, springfox 2.9.2

EDIT: I get jwt token after authentication like here: [How to configure oAuth2 with password flow with Swagger ui in spring boot rest application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054384/how-to-configure-oauth2-with-password-flow-with-swagger-ui-in-spring-boot-rest-), but I don't how to pass that value to http methods in swagger.

P.S. I don't want to use Spring Security.